# PowerShell receive vs. get verbs

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I've seen quite a few discussions on which verbs to use in your own PowerShell functions, but I haven't seen a clarification on using *Receive* vs. *Get*. They mean roughly the same thing to me, but *Receive* is supposed to be used specifically in situations involving *communications* (just type `Get-Verb` to see this).  Get, however, is in the *Common* group, so I'm really not sure which one to use.

I have a function that basically wraps a [RESTful](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Representational_state_transfer#RESTful_web_services) API and gets data from it (I use parameter sets for the different methods of the service). Right now the function is called Get-FooData. However, I'm thinking that I should possibly rename it to Receive-FooData since it is doing some communication.

I think I'm being too literal here in wanting to use *Receive*. My personal feeling is that *Get* sounds better, but I think that's just because I'm used to using it. What are your thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Although I'm proficient at PowerShell at only the amateur level, for me, "get" implies a much more forceful and in-charge type of code.  Meaning my code is going to initiate the action, and the other software will humbly respond to my request.

"Receive" sounds more docile, meaning the other software is really in charge.  So I might use Receive if the other software was for example putting out temperatures once a minute.  I'm going to receive the data, but the other software is doing its thing even if I wasn't there to receive it.

"Get" is shorter and most of the time I like to feel like my code is in charge.  Go with Get.

Comment: this is a good point and it helps me to cope with the name `Receive-Job` better.

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  Based on all comments, I've come to the conclusion that using Get for this particular case makes more sense than using Receive.  If for no other reason than the fact that technically, I'm doing a Send (an http request) and a Receive (getting the http response) so the total for all these operations is Get.  Thanks everyone for your responses.

Answer (score 5):

Use the noun to decide.  If your noun is the object that is being retrieved then use "GET".  If the noun is the mechanism by which you retrieve something, then use "RECEIVE".

e.g.

GET-BOOK -via REST

RECEIVE-REST -object book

Answer (score 4):

This is an interesting design question and I used to think on this choice a few times. According to these guidelines:

[Microsoft Command Line Standard](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156811.aspx)

and my feeling, too, I would use `Receive-X` name in cases when I also design one of the pair/satellite communication commands `Send-X`, `Connect-X`, etc. This approach improves discoverability: if I see the `Receive-X` then even without reading manuals I also expect additional commands to exist.

In some sense this is true for the native PowerShell command `Receive-Job`: we cannot just call it (unlike `Get-Item`, `Get-Process`, etc.), we have to initiate something which data can be received afterwards, namely at first we call the `Start-Job`. But personally, I would call it differently: `Get-JobResult` or something like that; to me this name would be less confusing: it's the job results that we get, not the job instances, and there are no other satellite commands like `Send-Job`. The name `Receive-Job` would be still available for something perhaps more adequate in the future.

I would go with `Get` in most cases. But if you actually really want a user to stop and think for a moment of why X is called `Receive`, not `Get`, and there are reasons for that then `Receive` might be suitable.

All in all, I have never really used the verb `Receive` in my cmdlet/script/function names: something always was not enough for making this choice.